# Docker Image not displaying in Web browser Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

I dockerized this https://github.com/dstar55/docker-hello-world-spring-boot example and deployed to my Azure kubernetes cluster and the image won't display in the internal or external IP. I can't seem to figure it out! It's driving me nuts. Any help or advise? Thanks!

It should just print hello world in the web browser.

I'm running Kubernetes in Windows 10. To access Kubernetes I'm running

az aks browse --resource-group docker-cluster --name final2

It then connects and I'm able to view the dashboard locally. When I click services to find the internal IP, when I type this in the browser I'm getting this error.

[image: The dashboard is up and this is the service I am trying to run in the browser]
[image: Error]

Yaml File -

```
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "spring-boot-example-3",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/spring-boot-example-3",
    "uid": "5fd1ec75-1c6d-11ea-bd7c-a63f8eaf100e",
    "resourceVersion": "11119",
    "generation": 2,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-12-11T23:24:27Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "spring-boot-example-3"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 3,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "k8s-app": "spring-boot-example-3"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "spring-boot-example-3",
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "k8s-app": "spring-boot-example-3"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "spring-boot-example-3",
            "image": "bcook88/spring-boot4",
            "resources": {},
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
            "securityContext": {
              "privileged": false
            }
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": "25%",
        "maxSurge": "25%"
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
    "progressDeadlineSeconds": 600
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 2,
    "replicas": 3,
    "updatedReplicas": 3,
    "readyReplicas": 3,
    "availableReplicas": 3,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Progressing",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2019-12-11T23:24:31Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-12-11T23:24:27Z",
        "reason": "NewReplicaSetAvailable",
        "message": "ReplicaSet \"spring-boot-example-3-66d65987d7\" has successfully progressed."
      },
      {
        "type": "Available",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2019-12-11T23:29:11Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-12-11T23:29:11Z",
        "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
        "message": "Deployment has minimum availability."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Serivce -

```
    {
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "spring-boot-example-3",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/spring-boot-example-3",
    "uid": "5fdaa8c1-1c6d-11ea-bd7c-a63f8eaf100e",
    "resourceVersion": "23726",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-12-11T23:24:27Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "spring-boot-example-3"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "tcp-80-85-67vw4",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 85,
        "nodePort": 30910
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "k8s-app": "spring-boot-example-3"
    },
    "clusterIP": "10.0.91.29",
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {
          "ip": "52.141.220.136"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The log shows that the application is running correctly and it does run correctly locally.

[image: Log showing successful execution. Should be able to pull this up in a web browser and see hello world]

Comment: Please edit your question to include enough detail so that someone can help debug your question.  What command exactly are you running?  What error do you get?  Also include relevant parts of your own application's source code or the deployment artifacts (Kubernetes YAML files, for example).

Comment: I added this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the screenshot that you provide, it seems you create the service with a NodePort type Load Balancer for your application. It means you cannot access your application outside the AKS cluster nodes(generally the nodes do not have public IP). And you need to change the port with 8080 instead of 80 like it shows in the Dockerfile.

The solution is that you need to recreate your service with the load balancer type, then it will give you an external IP which you can access outside the cluster through the browser.

And you can also take a look at [Publishing the services(service types)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

Comment: Hello, Thank you. I did try to create the service as a load balancer as well. I got the same issue.

Comment: @bcook Can you show your yaml file? And are you sure the image can run well locally?

Comment: yeah let met post it. Hang on just one sec.

Comment: @bcook I think you'd better add the message in your question, not in my answer.

Comment: @bcook I do not see the service in the file. Can you provide it?

Comment: @bcook OK, you use the wrong port. You need to expose the 8080 port, the Dockerfile shows the image use the 8080 port.

Comment: @bcook You can recreate the service with the right port, or use the command `kubectl edit svc spring-boot-example-3` and then change the targetPort into 8080.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't see an accept answer option. I posted your answer as the answer. lol. Please forgive me. I'm a newb on stackoverflow.